# How to Create a common vertical scroll bar for two adjacent div in two different containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to create a vertical scroll bar for the structure described below.

- While scrolling on resultLeft/resultRight headerLeft and headerRight should be fixed.
- Scroll bar should come along with resultRight Div and this should be in sync with resultLeft Div.

  ```
  <div class="mainContainer">
    <div class="leftContainer">
       <div class="headerLeft"></div>
       <div class="resultLeft" style="height:200px;">
             <p></p>
             <p></p>
             <p></p>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightContainer">
        <div class="headerRight"></div>
        <div class="resultRight" 
             style="height:200px;overflow-y:auto;">
             <p></p>
             <p></p>
             <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Something like this?**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.invisible').scroll(function() {
    $('.scroller').scrollTop($('.invisible').scrollTop());
  });
});
```

```css
.mainContainer {
  display: flex;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
}

.invisible {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  z-index: 1;
}

.leftContainer,
.rightContainer,
.invisibleContainer {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.headerLeft,
.headerRight {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
.invisible, .scroller {
  height: 150px;
}
.scroller {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.resultLeft,
.resultRight {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.resultLeft {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.resultRight {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="invisible">
    <div class="invisibleContainer">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="leftContainer">
    <div class="headerLeft">Header Left</div>
    <div class="scroller">
      <div class="resultLeft" style="height:200px;">
        <p>
          Scroll
          <br>Scroll
          <br>Scroll
          <br>Scroll
          <br>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightContainer">
    <div class="headerRight">Header Right</div>
    <div class="scroller">
      <div class="resultRight" style="height:200px;">
        <p>
          Scroll
          <br>Scroll
          <br>Scroll
          <br>Scroll
          <br>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I added two `.scroller` divs, in order to make the headers `position: absolute` on top of the divs that are actually doing the scrolling. Then I added an invisible container that is the same height as the scrollers, with content inside that is the same height as the content inside the scrollers. The JavaScript ensures that when you scroll the invisible div, the `.scroller` divs match the movement.

Comment: I need to add a movable bi-directional splitter which will be used to move "leftContainer" and "rightContainer" in left/right direction. Splitter will have same height as left and right containers. LeftContainer, Splitter and RightContainer width will be changed using JavaScript at runtime. Described in next comment.

Comment: <div class="leftContainer" style="width:500px;">   </div>
<div class="splitter" style="width:300px;height:200px">  </div>
<div class="rightContainer">   </div>

Comment: See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JavaSpyder/kznLzt26/). Is that what you're looking for?